# How to create a folder on Mac OSX hard drive programmatically

Tags: macos, directory

I need to create programmatically a folder named MY_FOLDER in the 'folder /Library/Application Support'. Somebody knows how to do this ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [`NSFileManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? Especially, [`createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW5).

Comment: This is the Cocoa way to do it, and sits atop `mkdir()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `mkdir()` system call, available in `<sys/stat.h>`.

Comment: This is the lowest-level way to do it that's available to most coders, but it works fine. Remember when using an `NSString` as your path: use `-fileSystemRepresentation` to get the appropriate C string to pass in.